# How to make a hivemq plugin that checks websocket origin?

Tags: mqtt, hivemq

I want to make a service which used by third party website, their users connect to my hivemq server using websocket, I want to just allow these authorized website users to connect to my broker.

So I want to write a hivemq plugin to check the origin.

I want to ask how to archive this, or if there's a better solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an hivemq custom extension that would authenticate the users based on a secret paraphrase with thier client_name.

Checking against origin is a bad design cause origin can be mocked for the client. Originally you should go with authentication.

For workaround, you can ask your mqtt clients name to define something as client_name_secret
Then on connection, you can match the name against a regex or you can also have a table for secret.

You can take a look on how to write an extention here -
https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/4.6/extensions/introduction.html#quickstart
https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-extension-sdk